# Python, JSON - Determining which downloaded JSON files are incomplete (Python3)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have scraped several thousand URL's containing JSON data from an online API and saved each URL as a separate file. However, many of these file downloads ended before they were complete (despite giving HTTP response code 200 and throwing no errors). What is a good way to determine which downloaded JSON files are complete, and which ended early?

- Each file contains JSON with an 'objects' array that should contain 1000 items (or less for an incomplete file). I have tried parsing the JSON file and checking the length of this objects array, but *even in the complete (good) files,* there are many non-escaped quotes and other characters in the JSON, which causes Python 3's json.loads() function to break with an errors like this (The JSON is valid):

  ```
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1078 ...
  ```
- I notice that many of the incomplete files end in a comma like this:

  ```
  …18:33:39 GMT"},
  ```

  because they finished loading an item in the 'objects' array but stopped before loading the next item, whereas the complete files do not have this comma:

  ```
  ...18:33:39 GMT"}
  ```

Currently, I am only checking completeness using a min-file-length threshold and by looking for files that end in a comma, but this feels hack-ish. *What is a better way to find incomplete JSON files, or a simple way to have the JSON decoder not break with odd or not-escaped characters (so I can check that   the Objects array contains all 1000 elements)?*

Comment: Maybe you could use the content-length header but really it sounds like something is amiss with the api

Comment: I have gotten several other strange errors with the API. However, the incomplete downloads seems to occur mostly when using Python Tornado to do the scraping (although no rhyme or reason to which ones -- some huge/slow response ones are fine, and some little/fast files fail for example), and not when using Python Requests. This makes me think it may be on my side.

Comment: yep, almost definitely then, I did not realise you were using async libs, only advice I can give without access to the code and or api is to debug your own code and get valid data, trying to clean the incomplete json is not going to really give you good data even if you manage to do it

Comment: Actually, I switched to Requests when I noticed the incomplete files, but I'm just tying to identify which files the Tornado script left incomplete so I can redo this (relatively small) subset with Requests (rather than redoing all downloads from Tornado)

Comment: Simplest way is just to catch the decode error and redownload that json